# Discord py detect reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am only trying to learn how to "read" the reaction on a message the same bot sends. I've been stuck for days. I looked it up but the only tutorials I find are with a specific message for roles. I don't care about that, I won't use a single message for the whole server, so there is no way I can get the ID for the message. I only want the bot to send a message, then the user reacts and the bot writes "you reacted with [emoji]".

I found some questions on this site, but they only managed to confuse me even more. Still, this is what I barely managed to make.

```
@bot.command()
async def react(ctx):
    await ctx.send("React to me!")

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
            await channel.send("{}, you responded with {}".format(user, reaction))
```

Comment: Do you know how to `wait_for` a reaction?

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a good example of this already in the documentation, you can find it here:

- [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for)

But to simplify the whole thing a bit, here is a **sample code**:

```py
@bot.command()
async def react(ctx):
    def check(reaction, user):  # Our check for the reaction
        return user == ctx.message.author  # We check that only the authors reaction counts

    await ctx.send("Please react to the message!")  # Message to react to

    reaction = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)  # Wait for a reaction
    await ctx.send(f"You reacted with: {reaction[0]}")  # With [0] we only display the emoji
```

**Here is how it looks like:**

[image: Reaction output]

*Without `reaction[0]` you would only get unnecessary information. `[0]` shows you only the first digit, in this case `Reaction emoji`.*